# Access individual values in array and display based on a condition

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

im having 2 arrays of data. The first array contains data of sales managers and the second contains the total value for each scode.

the below code shows the details of the sales managers and it works fine.

```
<?php  foreach ($allsales as $sales):?>
<?php if ($z != $sales['class']): ?>

  <tr>
  <td colspan = "6"><?php echo $sales['scode'];?><hr /> </td>
  </tr>

 <?php endif; ?>
 <tr>
  <td colspan = "2"><?php echo $sales['numb']?></td>
    <td><?php echo $sales['name']?></td>
    <td><?php echo $sales['scode']?></td>
    <td style="text-align: center"><?php echo $sales['months']?> Months</td>


    <?php
    $pending_unf =  $sales['amount'] * $sales['months']; 
    $pending = number_format((float)$pending_unf, 2, '.', '');
    ?>
    <td style="text-align: right"><?php echo $pending;?></td>

  </tr>
<tr>
  <td colspan = "6">Total Amount : XXXX</td>
  </tr>

  <?php $z = $sales['scode']; ?>
  <?php endforeach;?>
```

Below is my second array data

```
array(11) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["scode"]=>
    string(3) "10A"
    ["amount"]=>
    string(5) "12600"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    ["scode"]=>
    string(3) "10B"
    ["amount"]=>
    string(5) "51600"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(2) {
    ["scode"]=>
    string(3) "11A"
    ["amount"]=>
    string(5) "60000"
  }
  [3]=>
  array(2) {
    ["scode"]=>
    string(3) "9B"
    ["amount"]=>
    string(5) "30000"
  }
```

what i would like to do is get the amount from the second array and display it as the total as a new row at the end of each scode group as below

```
admission  name   months  scode
==================================
001        test1  3       10A
002        test2  5       10A
                Total    USD 1000

006        test3  7       15B
                Total    USD 1800

008        test4  1       15A
                Total    USD 800

011        test5  2       16C
                Total    USD 1600

051        test6  3       16A
012        test7  3       16A
                 Total    USD 2700
```

i just tried to use a foreach but it keeps on repeating in each and every row. but i want it to be displayed only at the end of each group.

so how do i access individual values in the second array and use it in a condition statement to display at the end of the last scode in each group?

any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is using two loops and an array of "already read" scodes.
Now in the first loop, each time I'd happen to find new scode on the frst array, I'd put it in array of "read scodes" and swich to inner loop, which goes through all array from current position and reads users with same scode.
Like this (asuming you have function to find "total value" in the secon array.

```
<?php
  $array1 = /*array of users*/;
  $array2 = /*array of total amouns of whatever*/;
  $read = array();  //theese scodes should be skipped next time
  for($i=0; $i<count($array1); $i++) {
    if(in_array($array1[$i]['scode'],$read))
      continue;  //If this user was already outputed, we skip him
                 //Othewise, we output all users with same SCODE
    $read[] = $array1[$i]['scode'];
    for($j=$i; $j<count($array1); $j++) {   //Note that I start from current position, all inputs before must be already read
      echo "User: {$array1[$j]['name']}\nScode: {$array1[$j]['scode']}\n\n";
    }
    echo "Total amount for theese users: ".get_total_amount($array1[$i]['scode'],$array2).PHP_EOL.PHP_EOL.PHP_EOL;  //finding amount for current scode.
  }

?>
```